# Consumer unit test with poll() never receives anything

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Consider the following code:

```
@Test(singleThreaded = true)
public class KafkaConsumerTest
{
  private KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> template;
  private DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> consumerFactory;
  private static final KafkaEmbedded EMBEDDED_KAFKA;
  static {
      EMBEDDED_KAFKA = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, "topic");
      try { EMBEDDED_KAFKA.before(); } catch (final Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(EMBEDDED_KAFKA.getBrokersAsString());
    senderProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    senderProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
    final ProducerFactory<String, byte[]> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(senderProps);
    this.template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    this.template.setDefaultTopic("topic");
    final Map<String, Object> consumerProps = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("sender", "false", EMBEDDED_KAFKA);
    this.consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps);
    this.consumerFactory.setValueDeserializer(new ByteArrayDeserializer());
    this.consumerFactory.setKeyDeserializer(new StringDeserializer());
  }

  @Test
  public void testSendToKafka() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    final String message = "42";
    final Message<byte[]> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "topic").build();
    this.template.send(msg).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    final Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer = this.consumerFactory.createConsumer();
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("topic"));
    final ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(10000);
    Assert.assertTrue(records.count() > 0);
    Assert.assertEquals(new String(records.iterator().next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), message);
    consumer.commitSync();
  }
}
```

I am trying to send a message to a `KafkaTemplate` and read it again using `Consumer.poll()`. The test framework I am using is *TestNG*.

Sending works, I have verified that using the "usual" code I found in the net (register a message listener on a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`).

Only, I never receive anything in the consumer. I have tried the same sequence (create `Consumer`, `poll()`) against a "real" Kafka installation, and it works.

Hence it looks like there is something wrong with the way I set up my `ConsumerFactory`? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
EMBEDDED_KAFKA.consumeFromAnEmbeddedTopic(consumer, "topic");
```

before publishing records via `KafkaTemplate`.

And then in the end of test for verification you need to use something like this:

```
ConsumerRecord<String, String> record = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(consumer,  "topic");
```

You can also use it the way you do, only what you are missing is a `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` as an `earliest`, because the default one is `latest`. That way a consumer added to the topic later won't see any records published before.

Comment: Thank you, the `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` setting was missing!